# Backtracking Problem or other better solution to find a sum from array

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I think this is backtracking problem but I just can't convert my thought to code. So sample working code will be appreciated. There might be other way to solve this, which I'd like to know too.

Given an array with N element. Divide into 3 separate array such that each array have equal sum (total element / 3). For the sake of this problem let's assume there will at least be one answer, and each item in array is not necessarily unique, and could be negative
for example:

```
Given: [13, 2, 9, 1, 4, 3, 7]
Return: [[13], [2, 1, 3, 7], [9, 4]]
```

Comment: Plenty of algorithms outlined at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning -- take your pick.

Comment: "Subset Sum" problem is well known to be **NP-hard.**  A intuitive approach is to allocate each number into K-buckets (eg. 3), if the sum of the bucket is total/k.